# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined while doing preview of react using vite preview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundler, vite

I am using `vite` version 3.0.0 inside the react project with `@vitejs/plugin-react` version 2.0.0.

**vite.conf.js -**

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
})
```

When I try to preview the website using `vite preview` command I get following error -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
> at index.aef3ad2c.js:346:199702
> at index.aef3ad2c.js:1:142
> at index.aef3ad2c.js:368:141758

Further, when I try to view the error line I see -

[image: error]

I tried finding out which package is using `crypto-js` using npm list `crypto-js` it returns empty like -

[image]

I tried removing node_modules and re-installing packages several times but still it's not working!

I also tried using `@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs` like -

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import {viteCommonjs, esbuildCommonjs} from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [viteCommonjs(), react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  esbuildOptions: {
    plugins: [esbuildCommonjs(['react-s3'])],
  },
})
```

Please help me find out the cause and possible turnaround!!!

## System Info

```bash
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
    CPU: (8) x64 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
    Memory: 3.31 GB / 15.79 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 8.16.0 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1266.0), Chromium (103.0.1264.62)
  npmPackages:
    @vitejs/plugin-react: ^2.0.0 => 2.0.1
    vite: ^3.0.0 => 3.0.8
```

#### Used Package Manager

npm

Comment: I am facing the same problem when serving production build.

Comment: I am unable to find the solution. Please reply if you found one. For now, I reverted back to CRA!!

Comment: also got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem then I found the solution by using Vite legacy plugin

[@vitejs/plugin-legacy](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-legacy)

example:

```
// vite.config.js
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'

export default {
  plugins: [
    legacy({
      targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
    }),
  ],
}
```

Comment: How do you use that library?

Answer (score 1):

According to [vite 3 esbuildOptions docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-esbuildoptions) you need to wrap esbuildOptions with optimizeDeps and your config should look like this:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import {viteCommonjs, esbuildCommonjs} from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [viteCommonjs(), react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      plugins: [esbuildCommonjs(['react-s3'])],
    },
  }
})
```